# How to hide dataframe index on streamlit?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit, pandas-styles

I want to use some pandas style resources and I want to hide table indexes on streamlit.

I tryed this:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


table1 = pd.DataFrame({'N':[10, 20, 30], 'mean':[4.1, 5.6, 6.3]})
st.dataframe(table1.style.hide_index().format(subset=['mean'],
             decimal=',', precision=2).bar(subset=['mean'], align="mid"))
```

but regardless the `.hide_index()` I got this:

[image]

Ideas to solve this?

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.

Comment: Can't you `table1.set_index('N')` than create `st.dataframe(table1)` ?

Comment: Ok, @furas, I've edited the post so that you can run the code. I'm using pandas 1.3.4 and some features might be recent.

Comment: @Jamjitul, this works, but the column "N" would have no label. It would be important that the table is properly formatted, with proper headings etc.

Comment: documentation for [st.dataframe](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.dataframe) shows `"Styler support is experimental!"` and maybe this can be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation for [st.dataframe](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.dataframe) shows `"Styler support is experimental!"`
and maybe this is the problem.

But I can get table without `index` if I use `.to_html()` and `st.write()`

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'N':[10, 20, 30], 'mean':[4.1, 5.6, 6.3]})

styler = df.style.hide_index().format(subset=['mean'], decimal=',', precision=2).bar(subset=['mean'], align="mid")

st.write(styler.to_html(), unsafe_allow_html=True)

#st.write(df.to_html(index=False), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using a CSS selector to remove the index column. Like explained in the [docs](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/using-streamlit/hide-row-indices-displaying-dataframe), you can do the following with `st.table`:

```
# import packages
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

# table
table1 = pd.DataFrame({'N':[10, 20, 30], 'mean':[4.1, 5.6, 6.3]})

# CSS to inject contained in a string
hide_table_row_index = """
            <style>
            thead tr th:first-child {display:none}
            tbody th {display:none}
            </style>
            """

# Inject CSS with Markdown
st.markdown(hide_table_row_index, unsafe_allow_html=True)

# Display a static table
st.table(table1.style.format(subset=['mean'],
             decimal=',', precision=2).bar(subset=['mean'], align="mid"))
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the index is gone. Keep in mind that the table function takes the full page.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code:

`st.dataframe(data,hide_index=True)`

st.dataframe function has an argument that is by default None, change it to True and it might work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please validate your response using provided input, as done in accepted answer.